# Change values of table in Access by pressing a button on a form

Tags: vba, ms-access, button, checkbox

On an Access form I want am trying to create a button where upon pressing it, it will change all of the values in a field within a specified table to false (i.e. uncheck all of the boxes in that field).

My current form name is `DataEntry`
The Button name is `Command77`

The name of the table is `TestTable`
The name of the field in `TestTable` is `CheckBox` (which has a Yes/No) format.

I've tried this code but it is not working. The error is Variable Not Defined.

```
Private Sub Command77_Click()
TestTable.CheckBox.Value = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your code looks for a form control named 'CheckBox' not a table field named `Checkbox`.

If you want to set the `Checkbox` field of **ALL** records to false, use this instead:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE TestTable SET Checkbox=False"
```

Comment: Be aware that this will cause action query confirmation prompts (which you can permanently disable in Access options).